# C - Retrieving a child's exit status that is larger than 8 bits

Tags: c, exec, fork

Note: For simplicity, I don't include much error checking and my sample code doesn't really serve any practical purpose.

**What I want:**

I want a program that `fork()`s a child process and has it invoke a process using `execl()`. My parent then retrieves the exit code for that process. This is fairly trivial.

**What I tried:**

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int ch = fork();
    if(ch == -1) {
        perror(NULL);
    }else if(ch == 0) {
        // In child, invoke process
        execl("/path/process", "process", 0);
    }else {
        // In parent, retrieve child exit code
        int status = 0;
        wait(&status);
        // print exit status
        if(WIFEXITED(status)) printf("%d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
    }
}
```

**My issue:**

`WEXITSTATUS()` only retrieves the lower 8 bits of the exit value while I need all the bits from the `int` value. Specifically, `process` performs a calculation and the result may be larger than 8 bits. It may even be negative, in which case, the highest bit will be needed to represent the correct value.

**What else I tried:**

Also, while looking around, I found the `pipe()` function. However, I'm not sure how to use it in this situation since, after calling `execl()`, I can't write to a file descriptor from within the child.

So how can I go about retrieving a child's exit status that is larger than 8 bits?

Comment: Related: [ExitCodes bigger than 255, possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/179565) - with a different API and some complication, it is actually possible to get the 32-bit value passed to `exit`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that what you are trying to accomplish it's possible, because in Linux (actually i think it's UX specific), a process exit code is an 8-bit number: 0-255 (and as a convention, 0 means success, anything else means error) and lots of stuff rely on this fact (including the macros you used). Take the following piece of code:

```
// a.c
int main() {
    return 257;
}
```

If you compile it (`gcc a.c`), and run the resulting executable (*a.out*) checking (`echo $?`) its exit code (that will be truncated by the OS; hmm or is it the shell?) it will output 1 (wrap around arithmetic): 257 % 256 = 1.

As an alternative as you mentioned, you could use `pipe` ([this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22502124/communication-between-child-and-parent-processes-in-c-linux-parent-process-not) is pretty descriptive) or sockets (`AF_UNIX` type).

Answer (score 0):

this code is from: [How to send a simple string between two programs using pipes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784500/how-to-send-a-simple-string-between-two-programs-using-pipes)

writer.c

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int fd;
    char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";

    /* create the FIFO (named pipe) */
    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);

    /* write "Hi" to the FIFO */
    fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
    write(fd, "Hi", sizeof("Hi"));
    close(fd);

    /* remove the FIFO */
    unlink(myfifo);

    return 0;
}
```

reader.c

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_BUF 1024

int main()
{
    int fd;
    char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";
    char buf[MAX_BUF];

    /* open, read, and display the message from the FIFO */
    fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
    read(fd, buf, MAX_BUF);
    printf("Received: %s\n", buf);
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

the code, probably the parent/reader, should delete the fifo node, perhaps by calling `rm`.
Otherwise the fifo entry is left in existence, even across a re-boot, just like any other file.