# Why do bitwise operation in shell script is difference with C?

Tags: shell

Recently I found a weird thing in shell script. It behave different with how I think when I using `~` (bitwise not operation). Following is sample code in shell:

```
function items() {
    local expected="$1"
    local input="$2"
    try "$expected" "int main(int argc, int argv) { $input }"
}
function expr() {
    local expected="$1"
    local input="$2"
    items "$expected" "exit($input);"
}
expr 18 "~237"
```

18 is expected value for ~237, but in ｃ is -238.

```
binary in 18 is  : .000010010
binary in 237 is : .011101101
```

I think result in C is right but why behave like this?

Comment: Which shell are you talking about? POSIX `sh`? PowerShell? CL? Fish? I tried your code, and I simply get "command not found: items".

Comment: @JörgWMittag Update for function `items`.  yes, I use `.sh`

Comment: "command not found: try"

Comment: On unix, the `exit` function [preserves only 8 bits of value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33289087/902497).

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks! I think u'r right!